# Clone jQuery input date picker element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the jQuery date picker and I want to clone the input element. The jQuery code seems to be working fine when cloning and static element but not with the date picker. Below is the code:

```
$(function(){
    var $button = $('.datepicker-input--checkin').clone();
    $('.package').html($button);
});

$(function(){    
    $('#thedate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        altField: '#thealtdate',
        altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
});
```

Shown Field :

```
<input id="thedate" type="text" class="datepicker-input--checkin" /><br />
```

Hidden Field :

```
<input id="thealtdate" type="text" class="datepicker-input--checkin" /><br />
<input id="thesubmit" type="button" value="Submit" />

<div class="package">
</div>
```

[Fiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/txqepe36/)

Comment: is this you are looking for https://jsfiddle.net/txqepe36/8/

Answer (score 0):

After cloning the input, you would need to initialize the datepicker again on the input.

You could do that by adding a class `datepicker` on the input intended to have the datepicker, and then initializing the datepicker (after cloning) using:

```
$(".package .datepicker").datepicker({
     dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
     altField: '#thealtdate',
     altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
```

Here's the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/txqepe36/3/

You could simplify the code even further by removing the datepicker initialization through element ID, since you have a class `datepicker` on both inputs expected to have a date picker control.

Your JS code could be simplified to:

```
 $(function() {
   var $button = $('.datepicker-input--checkin').clone();
   $('.package').html($button);

   $(".datepicker").datepicker({
     dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
     altField: '#thealtdate',
     altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
   });
 });
```

Note that you would need to add a `datepicker` class to the input. So it should look like:

```
<input id="thedate" type="text" class="datepicker-input--checkin datepicker" />
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/txqepe36/4/

Comment: sorry this clones the date picker but not the input value?

Comment: @user38208 Actually it does. You need to have any value in the datepicker **before** cloning. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/txqepe36/5/

Comment: Can it dynamically change as the date in the date picker changes?

Comment: @user38208 Not automatically. When you clone an object, it will only copy the HTML from source to destination. But there is no link between two elements.